# File.Copy slow on 20000 files

Tags: c#, file-copying

I'm trying to copy around +20000 files from one directory to another calling three separate File.Copy method. These files can range anywhere from 26KB to 3MB. The reason for using three methods is because I need to copy these files in the following order.
*.EXT1 => *.EXT2 => *.EXT3

The whole copy routine took a total of 2-3 hours. Am I doing something wrong here or is there a faster way of copying from one directory to another on the same network?

```
utility.GetFilesFromSource("*.EXT1");
utility.CopyFilesToPath(srcPath);

utility.GetFilesFromSource("*.EXT2");
utility.CopyFilesToPath(srcPath);

utility.GetFilesFromSource("*.EXT3");
utility.CopyFilesToPath(srcPath);


public static void GetFilesFromSource(string fileExtension)
{
   try
   {
      FileInfo[] Files = SourceDirectory.GetFiles(fileExtension)
                .Where(f => f.Name.Contains(suffixName)).ToArray();
   }
   catch
   {
      throw;
   }
}

public static void CopyFilesToPath(string path)
{
   try
   {
      foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
      {
         File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(path, file.Name));
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can potentially run this process in parallel.  However the hard drive is a lot slower than the CPU.  The bottleneck is going to be hardware not software.

Comment: Kinda off topic but Windows has a program called `Robocopy` and it's super fast.

Comment: I am not sure if there's anything you can do in code that would improve those times

Comment: Yes, I only want to copy them

Comment: Maybe you havent posted the exact code, but how is this supposed to work?  `GetFilesFromSource()` never returns the files, and the `Files` variable/property is never set (at least in the scope of `CopyFilesToPath()`

Comment: Only as a small note. Copying of many small files is slow even on SSD. Where it is only relatively slow on SSD, it will get slower for HDD, even slower for USB flash drive or SD card, and it is even slower on network *(depending also on protocol SMB/FTP e.t.c.)*. You can only try the copy with another application *(some sort of commander)* and compare the speed.

Comment: Perhaps [this project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/777322/A-Faster-File-Copy) might be of help?